# database error on upgrading the site

Tags: django, python-2.7, review-board

I have installed the reviewboard in virtual environment and have created site reviewboard on ubuntu 13.10 using apache2 with mod_wsgi.
when i hit the

```
http://localhost
```

i was asked to upgarde the site

> The version of Review Board running does not match the version the
>   site was last upgraded to. You are running 1.7.20 and the site was
>   last upgraded to 1.7.21.
>
> Please upgrade your site to fix this by running:

and on upgraded

```
$ rb-site upgrade /home/naveen/venv-review/reviewboard
```

got

i got following message:

> Updating database. This may take a while.
>
> The log output below, including warnings and errors, can be ignored
>   unless upgrade fails.
>
> ------------------  ------------------ Creating tables ... Installing custom SQL ... Installing indexes ... Installed
>   0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s) No evolution required.
>   -------------------  -------------------
>
> Resetting in-database caches. Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/naveen/venv-review/bin/rb-site", line 9, in 
>       load_entry_point('ReviewBoard==1.7.21', 'console_scripts', 'rb-site')()   File
>   "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ReviewBoard-1.7.21-py2.7.egg/reviewboard/cmdline/rbsite.py", line 2027, in main
>       command.run()   File "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ReviewBoard-1.7.21-py2.7.egg/reviewboard/cmdline/rbsite.py", line 1860, in run
>       site.run_manage_command("fixreviewcounts")   File "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ReviewBoard-1.7.21-py2.7.egg/reviewboard/cmdline/rbsite.py", line 562, in run_manage_command
>       execute_manager(reviewboard.settings, [**file**, cmd] + params)   File
>   "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 459, in execute_manager
>       utility.execute()   File "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 382, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 196, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **options.**dict**)   File "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 232, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 371, in handle
>       return self.handle_noargs(**options)   File "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ReviewBoard-1.7.21-py2.7.egg/reviewboard/reviews/management/commands/fixreviewcounts.py",
>   line 16, in handle_noargs
>       starred_public_request_count=None)   File "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py",
>   line 185, in update
>       return self.get_query_set().update(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py",
>   line 536, in update
>       rows = query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(None)   File "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
>   line 988, in execute_sql
>       cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)   File
>   "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
>   line 818, in execute_sql
>       cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/home/naveen/venv-review/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 344, in execute
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) django.db.utils.DatabaseError: attempt to write a readonly database

the sqlite database directory has been given access to server (www-data) like :
sudo chown www-data /home/naveen/venv-review/reviewboard/data

Does www-data should have read/write access of site , reviewboard, if it is the case ?

Update *****

checking apache2 user

```
ps aux | grep apache2

root      1146  0.0  0.0  84208  3928 ?        Ss   11:19   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  3632  0.1  0.6 698464 51056 ?        Sl   11:34   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  3742  0.1  0.6 698480 51032 ?        Sl   11:34   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
naveen    7162  0.0  0.0  13652   940 pts/1    S+   11:53   0:00 grep apache2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sqlite3 file, not only the directory, have to be owned and have to be writeable by the user running the web server.

so you may try running, from a terminal shell:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /home/naveen/venv-review/reviewboard/data
sudo chmod -R u+w /home/naveen/venv-review/reviewboard/data/*
```

the first command recursively change the owner of the files inside the folder, the second one ensures the users have writing permissions on these files.

Comment: ... And you received the identical error and traceback? Are you sure apache is running as www-data user?